# How to add a platform from within my VsPackage so users that install my addon can select that solution platform to build their projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

In Visual Studio 2013 I'm making a VsPackage that makes calls to an external cross compiler tool which can build for windows or linux.

I'd like to add linux32 and linux64 as selectable platforms when my vspackage is installed (in addition to the already present Win32 and x64). The user should not have to manually add any platforms themselves (my vspackage should initialize the platforms ready for them to select).

This is so I can detect the platform name string within my package and compile with the appropriate settings for that platform.

After some research I tried to do it like this:

```
            _applicationObject = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));

            EnvDTE.Project project;

            project = _applicationObject.Solution.Projects.Item(1);

            project.ConfigurationManager.AddPlatform("Linux32", "Win32", true);
```

But it returns an argument exception.

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in package_test.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```

What is the correct method for adding a platform from within a VsPackage (i.e. programatically)?